# Getting user initiated restart information of a VM through Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

Is there any way to get user initiated restart in azure VM as if the VM is started or restarted from portal then it will display in activity log but how can i get information about restart or start of VM if any user initiated it from inside the VM using Azure Log Analytics

I have tried sending the diagnostic VM Logs to log analytics but could not come up with anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

The answer to your question is to use a query something like shown below.

```
Event | where EventID == "1074" and Computer == "VMNAME" | project UserName, Computer
```

But for Log analytics workspace to monitor this kind of system events, you have to make sure that "system" event log name is added under your log analytics workspace advanced settings as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-windows-events#configuring-windows-event-logs).

Hope this helps!! Cheers!! :)